# C# Shell Extension

Tags: .net, shell

Is there an easier way of creating shell extensions in .NET than this?

http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ShellExtensions

The article is dated 2004.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With .NET 4 it is easier to write shell extensions in C#. Have a look at
[this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20101015055336/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx) for details of how to do it.

Comment: Not only is it safe, but it is *supported*.

Comment: Unfortunately, according to a recent update of that article, it's still not officially supported.